# Windows 2008 R2, heat map

Tags: windows-server-2008, performance-monitoring, capacity-planning

How do we get server heat map data from windows server based on memory usage and cpu usage. Our server Admins are not required to do this and our Dev team is trying to do this ourselves.I am trying to see if I can write some code or get this info from server anyway?

We need to see the usage (cpu/Memory) over month and weekly report and also daily graphs to plan for our capacity.

THanks.

Comment: That your sysadmins _aren't_ responsible for this is utterly absurd. This is what we _do_!

Answer (score 1):

First step is you have to collect the data. Windows does not keep historical performance data automatically. Look up Windows Performance Monitor and Data Collector Sets. There is lots of good information out there on basic performance monitoring and logging, so I won't go in to that here.

Second step is to process or visualize the data. The tools built in to the Windows Performance Monitor are very basic, but may suit your needs. There are third-party products that can consume Performance Monitor data to produce reports.

However, if your system administrators aren't already running a network or system monitoring tool, that's nearly criminal.

Comment: If the built in tools aren't sufficient then PRTG does a nice job of visualization and data rollup for historical trends.  Free for 100 sensors.  Other options would be Nagios, What'sUpGold, SolarWinds, etc.  Beyond the historical rollup, a 3rd party tool allows for installation on a separate machine and monitoring multiple machines from one dashboard.